# How identify a jar is applet?

Tags: java, jar, applet

how's your day? I have some questions, here they are.

1. How can we identify a jar is an applet?
2. If we haven't define main class in Manifest file how can an applet identify main class and execute it?

Thanks,
Muhammad Abdullah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/subclass.html

> Every Java applet must define a subclass of the Applet or JApplet class.

The JVM that executes the applet then calls the `public void init()` method.

1. You could use reflection to inspect all classes within the jar and figure out if there is a class that inherits from `Applet` or `JApplet`. But even if you'd get a positive match, this will only work as a hint...
2. This would not work and I can't see a case where this would make sense. You might have to elaborate on that requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any way to find whether a jar contains applet code or not unless there is a Manifest file or readme file in it which says so.

As for how to run it I suggest you go through [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html) link. Details deployment process is given along with the properties to be set in Manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot. A jar is a zip file. An applet is a special kind of Java program.
2. That isn't how applet(s) work.

Excerpted from here [Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html);
A Java applet is a type of Java program that a (web) browser enabled with Java technology can download and run from the internet and is typically embedded in a web page like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html)

```
<applet code=MyApplet.class 
    archive="MyApplet.jar"
    width="120" height="120">
</applet>
```

The MyApplet must extend from `java.applet.Applet` (or the Swing version of `javax.swing.JApplet`) - because that specifies the contract for the browser to manage the Applet's life-cycle.

Comment: let's say if I don't define archive tag in this applet tag will it work for me?
I am asking due to, I have few Jar applet sample which executes without defining archive tag,
will they execute?

Comment: Because they still specify the class, and it doesn't need any other classes?